# Session 'app': error when trying to run app

Tags: android, android-studio

I haven't been working in Android Studio last 2 weeks, now i come back to change something in my app, and i can't debug apps anymore on my smartphone.

I get this Event Log:

```
21:55:16 Gradle build finished in 4 sec
21:55:16 Session 'app': running
21:55:20 Session 'app': error
```

And my app doesn't start at all. This happens with all projects and they used to run on same device before perfectly. Apps are still working on Genymotion, but not on my smartphone.

I tried restarting everyting (AS, pc, phone) but nothing helped. There was exact same problem posted, but they got nothing. When trying to google i find only 3 relevant results, so probably very rare problem.

Logs aren't showing any unusual errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it.

I was experimenting something with my default install location before. At some point i set instal-location to 2, which means external storage (SD card).
This totally screws AS, so i had to revert it:

Run cmd from your sdk folder:

```
 adb devices
 adb shell pm set-install-location 1
```

**Edit:** As you can see from other answers you can get same error for other issues. You might want to look other answers and find what could be your problem.

Answer (score 4):

My root issue was what @fancy stated. However, I also had to go in to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart before it would work -- even after a full clean build.

To summarize:

- Check your gradle file for debuggable false/true (thanks @fancy)
- Invalidate caches & restart
- Check your install location (thanks @Gudin)
- Restart adb (thanks @ɯɐuʇɐs)

Answer (score 3):

For me it was a different issue.
I used the 'release' flavor for debugging purposes. If I switch the flavor to 'debug', it works perfectly fine again.

Apparently 'release' has the the 'debuggable' configuration set to 'false' and 'debug' to true.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of this, but apparently a recent edit to the grade file inadvertently removed the debuggable true line... whoops! Thank you. FWIW, what a lovely and descriptive error message we get when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

When the emulator has started, open Task Manager and in Processes, search for abd.exe and kill it. 
Its not exactly a solution, but after everything else fails, try this.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was that Android Studio couldn't find my Default Activity. 
I just deleted that class file and again copied t. When I specified the activity with intent filter to catch the MAIN action intent and that caused the 'Error Launching activity' issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I use emulator but when I run in Android phone it was solved.

- Clean or rebuild the app and run in Android phone.
- Uninstall the app if it is already there.